# some important questions during room migration process?

Tags: java, kotlin, build.gradle, android-room, database-migration

There are some basic but important info missed about room migration process. They may help other people. I've searched everywhere but found nothing. can anyone help?

1- When migration starts (while app setup, after first app startup after setup, or after first connection between app and db?)

2- If migration runs after setup, can I control it? showing upgrade messages before starting and after finishing?

3- Can we deted whether we don't need migration at all (like for new users)?

About migration testing:

1- how to re run test from beginning after each app running (e.g. runs every time from ver 1 to ver 2)?

After all of this, I have my own issue with testing,

Unresolved reference: MigrationTestHelper. I've tried the following dependencies with no result:

```
androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.4.2"
def room_version1 = "2.2.5"
def test_version = "1.4.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$test_version"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:$test_version"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version1"

androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.0.0"
testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"    //downgrade may solve
androidTestImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> 1- When migration starts (while app setup, after first app start-up after setup, or after first connection between app and db?)

The Migration starts when an attempt is made to access the database (not when you get an instance of the built database object). IF :-

1. the version number has been increased, AND

   1. a version number increase, is detected by checking the header of the database against the coded version number.
2. there is a migration available that covers the version number change.

   1. if no Migration then a failure will occur unless covered by a `.fallback???` is coded (most frequently `fallbackToDestructiveMigration`).

- By *"access the database"*, that is typically using one of the functions in a class that is annotated with @Doa. However, if you get a SupportSQLiteDatabase object (see below for an example, PS writable/readable no real difference).

This could assist in understanding:-

```
    db1 = UserDatabase.getInstance(this) /* Does not access the database */
    dao = db1.getAllDao() /* Does not access the database */
    val spprtDB = db.openHelper.writableDatabase /* will access the database */
    dao.invokeAFunction() /* accesses the database (assuming the function does something such as an @Query/ @Insert etc ) */
```

> If migration runs after setup, can I control it? showing upgrade messages before starting and after finishing?

Yes/No

You can't, at least easily, control it actually starting stopping (other than not changing/changing the version number).

But your Migration is then invoked, so you can have some form of control over what is done. However, afterwards the schema of the actual database (FOUND) is checked against the EXPECTED schema *(i.e. the @Entity annotated classes defined in the list of entities in the @Database annotated class)*. A failure to change the database as expected WILL result in an exception.

> 1- how to re run test from beginning after each app running (e.g. runs every time from ver 1 to ver 2)?

You could alter the database, outside of room and before the build (I would suggest) and change the version number to ver 1. e.g. Open the database as an SQLiteDatabase and then use the [setVersion](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#setVersion(int)) method.

- You may/may not wish to change the schema to the original.

Another way could be to have a second (original/base database) and copy that over, again prior to the the Room build.